# What is auto enrollment?

Tags: internship, linkedin

I applied for a job for a Machine Learning Intern from LinkedIn and then received this auto generated email.

```
Dear X,

I am pleased to extend the following offer of Machine Learning 
Trainee to you on behalf of Y You have been selected for the 
Machine Learning Trainee position.

Congratulations!

...


Regards,
Human Resources Team
Y
```

And then they give a link for their LMS. The following is their program structure:

[image: Y LMS guidelines]

The "internship" was mentioned to start in a few days and after that i received this letter:

```
Hello X,

You have been auto-enrolled into the course Machine Learning by 
your organization. Ensure you complete the Course before the due date. 

Please sign in to LMS for further details.

Thanks,
Training & Development Team
Y
```

What sort of internship is this, more specifically what does auto enrollment mean? What are its potential benefits?

Comment: Is this internship a paid internship? Is it remote? What does the original job description say? It sounds to me like you've been tricked into enrolling in a free unpaid online course/internship they're offering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what does auto enrollment mean?

Auto enrollment means that they have taken your information and added you to the list of people who are allowed to take the course. There is no need for you to ask permission to take the course, there is no need to wait for somebody to approve it. You are in.

You also have a deadline. So you should get started.

Based on what you attached to the question, you have one or more classes you have to complete before they assign you a project.

> What sort of internship is this, more specifically what does auto
> enrollment mean? What are its potential benefits?

We have no idea what this internship is. It might be great it might not be great.